# 0% accuracy with evaluate_generator but 75% accuracy during training with same data - what is going on?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm encountering a very strange with a keras model using ImageDataGenerator, fit_generator, and evaluate_generator.

I'm creating the model like so:

```
classes = <list of classes>
num_classes = len(classes)

pretrained_model = Sequential()
pretrained_model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg'))
pretrained_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

pretrained_model.layers[0].trainable = False

pretrained_model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

And I'm training it like this:

```
idg_final = ImageDataGenerator(
    data_format='channels_last',
    rescale=1./255,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    rotation_range=15,
)

traing_gen = idg_final.flow_from_directory('./train', classes=classes, target_size=(224, 224), class_mode='categorical')

pretrained_model.fit_generator(traing_gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

`fit_generator` prints `loss: 1.0297 - acc: 0.7546`.

Then, I am trying to evaluate the model on the **exact same data it was trained on.**

```
debug_gen = idg_final.flow_from_directory('./train', target_size=(224, 224), class_mode='categorical', classes=classes, shuffle=True)
print(pretrained_model.evaluate_generator(debug_gen, steps=100))
```

Which prints `[10.278913383483888, 0.0]`.

Why is the accuracy so different on the same exact data?

Edit: I also wanted to point out that sometimes the accuracy is above 0.0. For example, when I use a model trained with five epochs, `evaluate_accuracy` returns 6% accuracy.

---

Edit 2: Based on the answers below I made sure to train for more epochs and that the `ImageDataGenerator` for evaluation did not have random shifts and rotations. I'm still getting very high accuracy during training and extremely low accuracy during evaluation on the same dataset.

I'm training like

```
idg_final = ImageDataGenerator(
    data_format='channels_last',
    rescale=1./255,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    rotation_range=15,
)

traing_gen = idg_final.flow_from_directory('./train', classes=classes, target_size=(224, 224), class_mode='categorical')                  

pretrained_model.fit_generator(traing_gen, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

Which prints the following:

```
Found 9850 images belonging to 4251 classes.
Epoch 1/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3985s 13s/step - loss: 8.9218 - acc: 0.0860
Epoch 2/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3555s 12s/step - loss: 3.2710 - acc: 0.3403
Epoch 3/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3594s 12s/step - loss: 1.8597 - acc: 0.5836
Epoch 4/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3656s 12s/step - loss: 1.2712 - acc: 0.7058
Epoch 5/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3667s 12s/step - loss: 0.9556 - acc: 0.7795
Epoch 6/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3689s 12s/step - loss: 0.7665 - acc: 0.8207
Epoch 7/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3693s 12s/step - loss: 0.6581 - acc: 0.8498
Epoch 8/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3618s 12s/step - loss: 0.5874 - acc: 0.8636
Epoch 9/10
308/308 [==============================] - 3823s 12s/step - loss: 0.5144 - acc: 0.8797
Epoch 10/10
308/308 [==============================] - 4334s 14s/step - loss: 0.4835 - acc: 0.8854
```

And I'm evaluating like this on the **exact same dataset**

```
idg_debug = ImageDataGenerator(
    data_format='channels_last',
    rescale=1./255,
)

debug_gen = idg_debug.flow_from_directory('./train', target_size=(224, 224), class_mode='categorical', classes=classes)
print(pretrained_model.evaluate_generator(debug_gen))
```

Which prints the following very low accuracy: `[10.743386410747084, 0.0001015228426395939]`

---

The full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/sandlerben/a7979709a39f6172f7cf0e72e393ba58).

Comment: I ran into a problem that was very similar. I had a non deterministic order to my class labels in my preprocessing so the order between training and evaluating was different. It might be worth looking into that the ordering is the same.

Comment: Great idea. Would `list(train_df['Id'].unique())` for a pandas dataframe ever return different results?

Comment: I don't think it would. I verified that `debug_gen.class_indices == traing_gen.class_indices`.

Comment: I believe i was shuffling the data in my preprocess steps and adding classes dynamically as i came across them. But it seems you're not having the same problem. Always good to try for the low hanging fruit first though

Comment: Have you validated that the data being flowed into the fit_generator is correct?

Comment: I haven't, but I don't know how the same `ImageDataGenerator` on the same directory would return different `x` or `y` values?

Comment: Keras does the validation splitting before training. There is a chance that you have the classes unbalanced so its trying to predict on a class that it was never trained on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169803/discussion-between-ben-sandler-and-grant-williams).

Comment: @GrantWilliams This is not happening automatically. If you want a validation split you have to specify it using parameter `validation_split` in `fit_generator`. This was not done in the above code.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue? I still have this issue... :(

Answer (score 3):

Two things I suspect.

**1 - No, your data is not the same.**

You're using three types of augmentation in `ImageDataGenerator`, and it seems there isn't a random seed being set. So, test data is not equal to training data.

And as it seems, you're also training for only one epoch, which is very little (unless you really have tons of data, but since you're using augmentation, maybe that's not the case). (PS: I don't see the `steps_per_epoch` argument in your `fit_generator` call...)

So, if you want to see good results, here are some solutions:

- remove the augmentation arguments from the generator for this test (either training and test data) - This means, remove `width_shift_range`, `height_shift_range` and `rotation_range`;
- if not, train for really long, enough for your model to really get used to all kinds of augmented images (as it seems, five epochs seem still to be way too little);
- or set a random seed and guarantee that the test data is equal to the training data (argument `seed` in `flow_from_directory`)

**2 -** (This may happen if you're very new to Keras/programming, so please ignore if it's not the case) **You might be running the code that defines the model again when testing.**

If you run the code that defines the model again, it will replace all your previous training with random weights.

**3 - Since we're out of suggestions:**

Maybe save the weights instead of saving the model. I usually do this instead of saving the models. (For some reason I don't understand, I've never been able to load a model like that)

```
def createModel():
    ....

model = createModel()
...
model.fit_generator(....)

np.save('model_weights.npy',model.get_weights())

model = createModel()
model.set_weights(np.load('model_weights.npy'))
...
model.evaluate_generator(...)
```

---

**Hint:**

It's not related to the bug, but make sure that the base model layer is really layer 0. If I remember well, sequential models have an input layer and you should actually be making layer 1 untrainable instead.

Use the `model.summary()` to confirm the number of untrainable parameters.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'm going to use your suggestions to see if they improve my results. On your last point, model.summary() prints [this](https://gist.github.com/sandlerben/7f4decbfdbb52a005e72d2f3a2d4214f), so I do think layer 0 is resnet50.

Comment: Yes, it is :) -- Somewhere I found once a model that had an input layer. But I don't know where.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and they unfortunately didn't help. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Also I'm totally sure I'm not retraining the model during evaluation. You can see my full notebook code [here](https://gist.github.com/sandlerben/a7979709a39f6172f7cf0e72e393ba58).

Comment: Did you update your answer entirely and correctly? I still see the augmentation parameters in training data. It's still not the same dataset.

Comment: A suspicion: do you have files named as 'final_model' **and** 'final_model.h5'? -- If the save command is somenow adding the extension automatically, you may be loading a different model.

Comment: You can try to force deleting the files before saving (make sure the file is overriden by a new one).

Comment: It's true that it's not the exact same dataset but clearly the model is learning to account for the shifts and rotations by the tenth epoch (given the `0.8854` accuracy). Note also that the dataset is "different" on every different epoch because of the random shifts and rotations, but accuracy remains high.

There is only one model file, called `final_model`. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Weird.... as a last resource, I added option 3, saving only weights with numpy. (This is actually the only thing I do when working, because loading models never worked for me)

Comment: While in the notebook I have the line `pretrained_model = load_model('final_model')` when I last evaluated the model I actually didn't save/load the model, I just kept it in memory. So I don't think it's that either :/

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that for some reason `flow_from_directory` isn't properly using the `classes` argument. Is that possible?

Comment: Hey Daniel do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: No :( unfortunately