# Keras validation accuracy much lower than training accuracy even with the same dataset for both training and validation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

We tried the transfer learning with Keras ResNet50 application (Tensorflow as backend) with our own dataset for 2000 classes with 14000 images as training set and 5261 images as validation set. The training results we got are much different in both loss and accuracy for training vs validation. Then, we tried to use the same images for both training and validation, i.e. trained with 14000 images and validated with the same 14000 images, training results for the attempt are similar, i.e. high training accuracy and low validation accuracy.

Keras version: 2.1.6

Tensorflow version: 1.8.0

Code (same dataset for both training and validation) as below,

```python
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.callbacks import *
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from datetime import datetime
from keras.optimizers import SGD

import numpy as np

batch_size = 28   # tweak to your GPUs capacity
img_height = 224   # ResNetInceptionv2 & Xception like 299, ResNet50 & VGG like 224
img_width = img_height 
channels = 3
input_shape = (img_height, img_width, channels)
best_model = 'best_model.h5'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',  # this is the target directory
    target_size=(img_height, img_width), 
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)
n_of_train_samples = train_generator.samples

callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath=best_model, verbose=0, save_best_only=True),
             EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3, verbose=0)]

base_model = ResNet50(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional ResNet50 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

pool_layer = [layer for layer in base_model.layers if layer.name == 'avg_pool'][0]
base_model = Model(base_model.input, pool_layer.input)
base_model.layers.pop()

dropout=[.25,.25]
dense=1024
last = base_model.output
a = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(7,7),name='maxpool')(last)
b = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7,7),name='avgpool')(last)
x = concatenate([a,b], axis = 1)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(dense, init='uniform', activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(dropout[0])(x)
x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(base_model.input, outputs=x)

print("Start time: %s" % str(datetime.now()))

# compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers to non-trainable)
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=n_of_train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs=3,
    validation_data=train_generator,
    validation_steps=n_of_train_samples//batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks)

print("End time: %s" % str(datetime.now()))
```

Training result as below

```python
Found 14306 images belonging to 2000 classes.
Start time: 2018-05-21 10:51:34.459545
Epoch 1/3
510/510 [==============================] - 10459s 21s/step - loss: 5.6433 - acc: 0.1538 - val_loss: 9.8465 - val_acc: 0.0024
Epoch 2/3
510/510 [==============================] - 10258s 20s/step - loss: 1.3632 - acc: 0.8550 - val_loss: 10.3264 - val_acc: 0.0044
Epoch 3/3
510/510 [==============================] - 63640s 125s/step - loss: 0.2367 - acc: 0.9886 - val_loss: 10.4537 - val_acc: 0.0034
End time: 2018-05-22 10:17:42.028052
```

We understood that we shouldn't use the same dataset for both training and validation but we just could not understand why Keras give us high differences in both loss and accuracy for training vs validation when the dataset are the same for both training and validation.

ps. We tried the same dataset, i.e 2000 classes with 14000 images as training set and 5261 images as validation set with fast.ai library ResNet50 and the training loss and validation loss are not much difference. Codes and results with fast.ai library as below

```python
from fastai.imports import *
from fastai.transforms import *
from fastai.conv_learner import *
from fastai.model import *
from fastai.dataset import *
from fastai.sgdr import *
from fastai.plots import *
from datetime import datetime

PATH = "data/"
sz=224
arch=resnet50
bs=28

tfms = tfms_from_model(arch, sz)
data = ImageClassifierData.from_paths(PATH, tfms=tfms, bs=bs)
learn = ConvLearner.pretrained(arch, data, precompute=False)

print("Start time: %s" % str(datetime.now()))
learn.fit(1e-2, 5)
print("End time: %s" % str(datetime.now()))

Start time: 2018-05-02 18:08:51.644750

  0%|          | 1/487 [00:14<2:00:00, 14.81s/it, loss=tensor(7.5704)]

[0.      6.13229 5.2504  0.26458]                                     
[1.      3.70098 2.74378 0.6752 ]                                     
[2.      1.80197 1.08414 0.88106]                                     
[3.      0.83221 0.50391 0.9424 ]                                     
[4.      0.45565 0.31056 0.95554]                                     

End time: 2018-05-03 00:27:13.147758
```

Comment: You're not the first person with this same problem.... this link doesn't have an answer, but maybe you could ask the questioner if they found a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031553/0-accuracy-with-evaluate-generator-but-75-accuracy-during-training-with-same-d/50121735#50121735

Comment: I think this is worthy creating an issue at the keras github repository...

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a suggestion to see the non-affected loss/metrics per batch:

```
def batchEnd(batch,logs):
    print("\nfinished batch " + str(batch) + ": " + str(logs) + "\n")

metricCallback = LambdaCallback(on_batch_end=batchEnd)

callbacks = [  metricCallback, 
               ModelCheckpoint(filepath=best_model, verbose=0, save_best_only=True),
               EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3, verbose=0)]
```

With this, you will see the metrics for each batch without the influence of other batches. (Assuming Keras does some kind of averaging/totaling when it shows the metrics for an epoch).

Answer (score 0):

each time you start your fitting - it can give different results, because initial weights are being loaded different (in multi-thread env. of the library)... and if you have imbalanced dataset - it is also hard to think about the correctness of results... besides I always believe that minimum 50-100 epochs are needed to get rather reliable result (3 is not sufficient)